# Angular app uses express-session to authenticate both port 3000 and port 4200

Tags: node.js, angular, express, session, express-session

Using angular-cli to develop angular,

`ng serve` is on port 4200
`node server.js` is on port 3000

I want to login using express login page.

Because the cookie and session are domain-specific. Since the ports are different, I can login myself via port 3000 on the express page, as all the login is done on the express side.

How I can use the angular app?

Expressjs won't be able to receive both the session and cookie via XHR in the app.

So visiting the same `localhost:3000/api/user` route

Within angular, it's XHR hit rendered 302 redirect just like not logged-in user
But visiting it directly, it's 200.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'somerandonstuffs',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true }
}));

const authUser = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies['connect.sid']) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect(config.serverHost + '/login');
    }
};

app.route('/login')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/login.html');
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
            req.session.user = {
                id: 'x@x.x'
            };
            res.redirect(config.clientHost);
        }
    });

app.all('/*', authUser, function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

Actually, at least someone can tell me whether if shared domain(port) can work at all with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You run Angular CLI server on 4200 (only) for development. And if you want to hit port 3000 api use proxy configuration:

In angular.json:

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "cleanup:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
      },
```

and in proxy.conf.json define redirect:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Now in regular mode, you use the same express server to serve up Angular.

```
   "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../express/webapp"
```

Or wherever your express static directory is.

Comment: Thanks! Near perfect! It redirects to login page successfully when I try to visit 3000. But I couldn't get it redirect if I visit 4200.